# is_page($id) not working for index-php in child-theme

Tags: php, wordpress, parent-child

I want to limit the usage of a plug-in to the child-theme (called "intranet") only.
The file is located in `mytheme/intranet/index.php`, and is used as a template by a page named "Intranet" created in WP admin.
The URL is `www.mysite.com/intranet`

I have tried both targeting post-id ("100") and page-slug ("intranet") like this:

```
if (is_page( 100 )) {               
    //run pluggin
    }

if (is_page( 'intranet' )) {                
//run pluggin
}
```

This works however when targeting a page using template `mytheme/intranet/custom-page-template.php` in the child-theme (both id and slug).

I also tried targeting the uri:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if ( strpos($uri, 'child-theme/index.php') ) {
     //run pluggin
}
```

Any ideas why it isn't working?

Comment: use is_page(id/slug) function

Comment: Sry, that was just a typo... I actually used `is_page()`in code.

Comment: are u using custom query in your code??

Comment: If you are using wp_query the add <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> in your code other wise this code put into function.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a wp_reset_query function call after your loop on the homepage template.

If you're using a custom query on the home page and not used wp_reset_query, then the conditional check will always point to the last post fetched by that custom query hence failing to check if homepage.

OR

Try this

```
<?php if (get_the_ID()==100): ?>
  <!-- Google Analytics Content Experiment code -->
<?php endif; ?>
```